# Data Cleaning without pandas

Tags: python, data-cleaning, data

How can I clean a data csv file with the restriction of only using python and its standard library? No third party programmes such as pandas can be used. For example: removing a column from the dataset, correcting spelling mistakes, inconsistencies in data formatting, null entries etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following solution uses the library `csv`. The `if` statement can drop a column before loading the whole csv file. You will need to create your own list for punctuation to remove. It should be noted that if you have a text with a comma in it, it will be in two different keys in your dictionary. In other words, you should clear commas beforehand. Moreover, the stopwords list should be in lowercase letters, since the first function will change the sentences into lowercase. The result would be a list with ordered dictionaries. I hope this answer helps you with your problem.

```
path=r"C:\Users\****\****\file_name.csv".replace('\\', '/')

import csv
my_data=[]
punctuations_list=[':','.','!','#']
stopwords_list=['i','there','it','this','is']

def remove_character(give_string):
    return "".join([letter for letter in give_string.lower() if letter not in punctuations_list])
def remove_words(give_string):
    return " ".join([word for word in give_string.split(" ") if word not in stopwords_list])

with open(path) as csvfile:
    reader = csv.DictReader(csvfile, fieldnames=('1stcol','2ndcol','3rdcol'))
    for row in reader:
        if '2ndcol' in row.keys(): #Deletes a column(rather a pair of key value from dictionary)
            del(row['2ndcol'])
        row['3rdcol']=remove_words(remove_character(row['3rdcol'])) #Make some cleaning to the text in a specific column
        my_data.append(row)
```

Answer (score 0):

I work in a restricted environment and I've heard of others that are worse than mine, but no pandas??? Geez, that's rough!

You could do this by reading through the file, line-by-line, column by column and then applying a series of your own functions to test/fix the data in each cell. But you would have to have all of the defined needs well ahead of time and then write the methods to get each data point in a methodical fashion.

So it *can* be done but you're doing a massive end-run around pandas to get there.

Answer (score 0):

This answer would depend on access to command line tools but you could use the os module (import os)to call any number of command line tools to clean the data. What you call would depend on what is available on your system and whether you are able to run your own scripts,e.g. bash script, csvkit, xvs (rust). So would need more information to give more specific advice.